# Having trouble calling textFieldShouldReturn from a UITextField within a custom UITableCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to call textFieldShouldReturn on a UITextField within a custom UITableCell I have on my table view. I use this bit of code to grab the index path of the cell, I found this method on stackoverflow in another post:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(friendTableCell*)[[textField superview] superview]];
```

I don't have any errors, when I compile and run, but when I select a cell, enter text, and try to hit return on the keyboard, nothing happens. I have excluded the rest of the code that should be called because it is rather lengthy, and I have tested in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it works. I can include it if someone really cares to see though. I thought that perhaps my delegate wasn't set properly for the keyboard, but I have include UITextFieldDelegate in my header, and I'm not really sure how else to set the delegate for the keyboard seeing as I'm accessing a custom cell within a tableview. If someone has an idea of what to do, or an alternative method, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

**UPDATE - Complete textFieldShouldReturn method**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(friendTableCell*)[[[textField superview] superview] superview]];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [self.usernameSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionUser = [self.sortedUsernames objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    self.recipient = [sectionUser objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    friendTableCell *cell = (friendTableCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *sendingUser = self.currentUser.username;
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %@", [sendingUser uppercaseString]];

    if ([self.locationSwitch isOn])
    {
        if ([cell.message.text length] > 0)
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %@ %@", [sendingUser uppercaseString],cell.message.text];
        }

    CLLocation *location = locationManager.location;
    if(!location)
    {
        [cell closeMessage:self];
    }

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
        PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
        PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Location"];
        [object setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"location"];
        [object setObject:self.recipient.objectId forKey:@"recipient"];

        [object saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if(succeeded){
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Location was sent!"message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];

                dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                    PFQuery *locationQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Location"];
                    [locationQuery whereKey:@"recipient" equalTo:self.recipient.objectId];

                    /****** CHANGE THE getFirstObjectInBackground method so it doesn't take the first each time
                     or DELETE THE LOCATION after it has been viewed **************/

                    [locationQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                        }
                        else {
                            self.locationId = object.objectId;
                            NSLog(@"Here is you location ID: %@", self.locationId);

                            dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                                self.data = @{
                                              @"alert":message,
                                              @"locationId":self.locationId
                                              };

                                PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
                                [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.recipient.objectId];
                                PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query];
                                [query whereKey:@"currentUser" matchesQuery:userQuery];

                                PFPush *push= [[PFPush alloc]init];
                                [push setQuery:query];
                                [push setData:self.data];
                                [push sendPushInBackground];
                            });
                        }
                    }];
                });
            }
        }];
    });
}



else if ([cell.message.text length] > 0)
{
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %@ %@", [sendingUser uppercaseString],cell.message.text];

    PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
    [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.recipient.objectId];
    PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query];
    [query whereKey:@"currentUser" matchesQuery:userQuery];

    PFPush *push= [[PFPush alloc]init];
    [push setQuery:query];
    [push setMessage:message];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
}

else
{
    PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
    [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.recipient.objectId];
    PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query];
    [query whereKey:@"currentUser" matchesQuery:userQuery];

    PFPush *push= [[PFPush alloc]init];
    [push setQuery:query];
    [push setMessage:message];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
}

NSLog(@"Message sent!");
[cell closeMessage:self];
[cell resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: have you bind delegate for your textfield when adding to custom table cell? `textField.delegate = self` ?

Comment: yes, the textfield has it's delegate set in the custom uitablecell nib files.

Comment: Where are you trying to access textFieldShouldReturn , from CustomCell or from class with tableView?

Comment: from the class with the tableView

Comment: i think you will have to include 'cell.textField.delegate = self' in your CellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: unfortunately it's not working :/...thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(friendTableCell*)[[[textField superview] superview] superview]];` as there is another scrollview layer in between container view and cell .

Also i can see you have written  `[cell resignFirstResponder];` instead you should use `[textField resignResponder]`
Hope this would work..

Comment: Ok...it worked initially, but then it stopped. I'm not really sure what that means. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, it worked and then stopped, How can it possible, if it works then it would work forever.. Clean and build again. Also if it works dont forget to accept the answer :) Also post you detail code.

Comment: That's why I'm so confused. I initially loaded it onto my phone and it worked fine. Then I went to work on another completely unrelated piece of code, and when I ran the build again and tried using my app, the "send" button was no longer working. I have updated my code above to include my entire textFieldShouldReturn method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your problem exactly , - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField is not calling after tapping return key in keyboard, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is not calling when I tap return key in keyboard

Comment: I'm going to say that you're code is correct. It does work on some builds, yet fails to work on others, so I'm not sure what is going on exactly. The fact that it does work some of the time leads me to believe maybe I have memory management issues or something else. I'll keep searching.